# Append array to a particular array element

Tags: php, arrays

I currently have this `array` structure which I will later convert into `JSON`:

```
Array
(
    [response] => Array
        (
            [timestamp] => 1391457939
            [crimes] => Array
                (
                    [year] => 6-2013
                )
        )
)
```

I want to know if there is a way to append array data to a selected array node without specifying the root array node. For example, I want to append the following `array` to the `crimes` array from above:

```
array(
    "Robbery" => 123,
    "Burglary" => 456
);
```

So it should look like this:

```
Array
(
    [response] => Array
        (
            [timestamp] => 1391457939
            [crimes] => Array
                (
                    [year] => 6-2013
                    [Robbery] => 123 //Appended Data
                    [Burglary] => 456 //Appended Data
                )
        )
)
```

Function:

```
    public function addDataToJSONResp($parentArrayName, $arrayData){

        //jsonResponse is the main array which currently holds the array data which will be converted into JSON at a later step.
        if(isset($this->jsonResponse)){
            //Do processing here
            //Search for parent array node in jsonResponse.
            //append $arrayData to jsonResponse if it finds the parent array element.
        }else{
            //error
        }
    }
```

The function used:

```
    private function addDataToJSONResp($nodeName, &$array, $data) {
       foreach ($array as $key => $val) {

           if ($key == $nodeName) {

               foreach($data as $k => &$v){
                    $array[$key][$k] = $v;
                }

           }else if(is_array($val)){
                $this->addDataToJSONResp($nodeName, $val, $data);
           }
       }
    }
```

Comment: You have to specify the structure _somehow_. What are the business rules to decide where to append the data?

Comment: I will have a function which will allow the user to specify the parent name of the array which they want to append the data to.

Comment: @user3166216 Show us the signature of this function that you now mention...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what you wanted to achieve?

```
<?php


/**
 * We're passing the $inputArray in as reference
 * since we want the passed array to be changed 
 * right away
 *
 * $dataArray is the array we want to append
 *
 * $node, is the array key of the array we want our data 
 * to append on
 **/

function pushToNode(&$inputArray, $dataArray, $node)
{
    // Traverse our Input array
    foreach($inputArray AS $key => &$value)
    {
        // If the key of the current iteration
        // matches the node we want to append
        // our data on, we're done.
        if($key === $node){
            // We just iterate trough our data array...
            foreach($dataArray AS $k => &$v)
            {   
                // and append the keys and the values 
                // to the array we wanted to.
                $inputArray[$key][$k] = $v;
            }
            return;
        }
        // Since you don't want to specify the root node
        // our function needs to be recursive
        if(is_array($value))
        {
            pushToNode($value, $dataArray, $node);
        }
    }
}

$myArray = [

    'response' => [
        'timestamp' => 1293845329,
        'crimes' => [
            'year' => '1995'
        ]
    ]

];

$crimes = [
    'robbery'  => 'I robbed someone, wow!',
    'burglary' => 'Oh look. Catch me if you can.'
];

pushToNode($myArray, $crimes, 'crimes');

echo "<pre>";
print_r($myArray);
echo "</pre>";
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [response] => Array
        (
            [timestamp] => 1293845329
            [crimes] => Array
                (
                    [year] => 1995
                    [robbery] => I robbed someone, wow!
                    [burglary] => Oh look. Catch me if you can.
                )

        )

)
```

The important code is commented, but basically we're traversing the input array recursively. If we are at the node we want to append our data on, we append it and return. Our Input Array is passed in as reference, so the array itself will get changed.

Comment: I tried to avoid the inner foreach by using array_walk, but messed something up with the references here. I'd appreciate if anybody could  give me a wink on how to do it "cleaner".

Comment: `$inputArray[$key][$k] = $v;` does not append the value to the array.

Comment: How did you use the function? I fully tested it and it worked flawlessly. I'll add the output.

Comment: Updated my question with the function that I used. Its the bottom one.

Comment: Ok. I finally found the error. I missed the `&` from the first `foreach` `$value`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can store a reference to the sub-array in a variable:

```
$root = array(
    'response' => array(
        'timestamp' => 1391457939,
        'crimes' => array(
            'year' => '6-2013'
        )
     )
);

$crimes = &$root['response']['crimes'];
```

Now, whenever you make a change to `$crimes`, it will be reflected in `$root`.

In order to append the array:

```
array(
    "Robbery" => 123,
    "Burglary" => 456
);
```

You could then do:

```
$crimes = array_merge($crimes, array(
    "Robbery" => 123,
    "Burglary" => 456
));
```

Alternatively:

```
$crimes['Robbery'] = 123;
$crimes['Burglary'] = 456;
```

Outputs

```
Array
(
    [response] => Array
        (
            [timestamp] => 1391457939
            [crimes] => Array
                (
                    [year] => 6-2013
                    [Robbery] => 123
                    [Burglary] => 456
                )

        )

)
```

Here is a [demonstration](http://ideone.com/d164TI), hosted at ideone.com.